# changing textview color when a button with that color is clicked

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-button

I want to change the color of certain text residing in different class. when the button is clicked which is in a different activity, the text color should be changed to that of button's color appearing or labeling. e.g. if the button show or label color green, when user clicked it that color(green) should be applied to the text. 
I don't know how to achieve this...

NOTE: the buttons and the text are in different classes.

please help !

your help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Use a static variable to store the status of required color of textView. And onResume   () of the activity update the color of textView

Comment: I would suggest you to use `SharedPreference` for this. When a button is clicked, you save the colour of the button in `SharedPreference` and then before loading the next `Activity`, check the colour in `SharedPreference` and set the color of the text programmatically.